# laravel:Controller already exists

Tags: laravel, controller, addition

## php artisan make:controller StudViewController --resource --model=studView

And the answer is

`Controller already exists!`

I've tried

1. php artisan config:clear
2. php artisan cache:clear
3. composer dump-autoload

   Any help guys  ?
   thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means controller with the name `StudViewController` in `Http/Controllers` folder already exists. Double check if there really exists controller with this name.

Comment: how can i remove that exists one ?

Comment: Delete it as you delete simple file

Comment: And check that you didn't use that controller in your other files including `routes/web.php` or `routes/api/php`

Comment: I have exactly the same problem as the OP. I attempted to create a controller using `artisan make:controller NewController` while an error was present in a config file; as a result the operation failed. After addressing the error in the config file, the artisan command now fails with the message `Controller already exists!`. Yet AFAICT the contoller never got created; there is no file with that name in my Controllers directory, and a search of the entire project directory for that controller name returns no results. Yet artisan still reckons the controller exists? :/ Any ideas..?

Comment: Like the OP I have tried `artisan config:clear && artisan cache:clear && composer dump-autoload` to no avail

Comment: Maybe you have controller with that namespace but with different filename

Answer (score 0):

Try running the command,

composer update –no-scripts

and then create the controller. It worked in exactly the same situation vis-a-vis displayed "Controller already exists!" but actually not available in the the workspace Controllers folder.